# closed-form of an integral that may relate to the elliptic integral

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form

I want to deal with the integral of the form
$$
F_{\nu} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}+\frac{\nu}{2}\sqrt{(a^2-b^2)^2+16ab\cos^2k}}}\;dk \\
\;\;\;\;\;\;
= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}+\frac{\nu}{2}\sqrt{(a^2-b^2)^2+16ab\cos^2k}}}\;dk
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are two real integrals, $\nu=\pm1$. Specically, if $a=b$, the integral above is just
$$
F_{\nu} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+2\nu a\vert\cos k\vert}}\;dk  \\
\;\;\;\;\;\;
= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+2\nu a\cos k}}\;dk
$$
and the summation of $F_++F_-$ relates to the [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) of the first kind. But for general case where $a\neq b$, how to handle the integral? If a close-form exist? Any comment or solution will be welcomed.

EDIT (8 Dec. 2016):

In order to avoid the confusions, I shall introduce the equivalent integral (up to a constant coefficient)
$$
F_{\nu} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\nu\sqrt{q^2+d^2\cos^2k}}}\;dk 
$$
where $q\in(-1,1)$, $d\in[0,1)$, and $\nu=\pm1$. It is alse assumed that $q^2+d^2<1$, so do not warry about the complex number.

Comment: May we assume both $a$ and $b$ are positive? If not, complex numbers will be necessary.

Comment: @DavidH: for sure. Any suggestion? Could you please provide me with some related papers  or links?

Comment: I've worked on this integral off and on over the holidays, and while I was hopeful at first, I've given up on finding a closed form in terms of elliptic integrals. Your integral is equivalent to a hyper-elliptic integral with degree $7$ polynomial under the square-root. It can also be written as a generalized Appell hypergeometric function, but that hardly counts as a closed form.

Comment: @DavidH: Thanks very very much for your time and patience! I will check it later.

Comment: Anytime. Hyper-elliptic integrals are actually a subject a major interest to me at the moment, so it was time well spent.